# Apache Ignite: Off-heap eviction not working

Tags: ignite, gridgain, distributed-caching, apacheignite

I am using Ignite 2.15 and have a DataRegion configured with 'PageEvictionMode=RANDOM_2_LRU', yet I end up getting a `IgniteOutOfMemoryException` with the following message:

```
Out of memory in data region [name=SAMPLE_TEST, initSize=10.0 MiB, maxSize=60.0 MiB, persistenceEnabled=false] Try the following:
^-- Increase maximum off-heap memory size (DataRegionConfiguration.maxSize)
^-- Enable Ignite persistence (DataRegionConfiguration.persistenceEnabled)
^-- Enable eviction or expiration policies
```

Any idea what is going on and why the eviction is not working?

TIA

Comment: Share your full data region and cache confs if it's ok. IMO 60 Mb is a very small region, what kind of entities do you have?

Comment: This is not the production setting. But i wanted to validate the eviction behavior so, i kept this small.

Comment: What are your objects? How big? How many caches do you have, cache groups? How many partitions are stored locally?